# How to clear cache in AngularJS application in javascript when running the application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I'm creating an application using AngularJS. It's for a client. And he is using that now. Every time I create and hosted my new version, client cannot get that. He has to clear cache manually and get the new update. Can I clear all cache in Javascript ? Is there any code to do that ?

Comment: hi checkout this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647435/angular-disable-cached-partials-in-production

Comment: I have did it once, using a version identifier. It is quite complex in matter of answer of your question. In case you can't find suggestion of @thomasbabuj works. And interesting with mine one, I will make an answer for you (quite long so I am lazy) :p

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to adding  version to the script's source file, i.e.,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filename?versionnumber"></script>
```